# Android Install to Tablet places icons for all Activities

Tags: android, eclipse, icons, installation

**THE SETUP:**
Developing API 16 Android app with Eclipse and installing on Tablet when testing.

**THE PROBLEM:**
Every time I use Eclipse to install the app and run it on the actual tablet, it creates an application icon for every single activity in the application that is visible from the main dashboard, whether it is called or not.

**THE QUESTIONS:**

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I stop it?
3. Loosely related question - I've seen many people looking for an easy way to make a simple installable file to put the appplication onto a tablet.  I have considered using a signed application package and a third-party app installer from SD card.  Are there any other suggested ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

If we have to guess, it's because you have the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` on all those activities in your manifest.

> How do I stop it?

Only put that `<intent-filter>` on the activity (or activities) that should appear in the launcher.

> I've seen many people looking for an easy way to make a simple installable file to put the appplication onto a tablet.

I have no idea what you consider "a simple installable file" is.

> I have considered using a signed application package and a third-party app installer from SD card.

I have no idea what you consider "a third-party app installer" to be.

Comment: A simple installable file: a file that can be moved onto the SD card, with all the necessary information to install the application (like a Windows .CAB file)

A third-party app installer: something like AppsInstaller by modmymobile